# Secure FTP Solution?

Tags: windows-server-2003, ftp

Here's the scenario.  We have outside consultants that get AD usernames and passwords to our network.  Our web server (Win 2003) hosts multiple web sites that we would like to give out FTP access to the various people that need to update their files.  We work in a mixed environment (Mac / Linux / Windows) and need to provide a client to streamline the instructions that we give out to everyone on how to update their websites.  Ideally this would be a thin client that the end user would download through their browsers.  We would like to be able to assign AD users to the folder that their website resides in.

Is there any FTP server solutions out there that provide FTPS (we don't need full encryption, just the authentication handshake) and a client so that the user experience is the same accross the board for Windows servers and provide the user assignment to folders?

Answer (score 1):

[XlightFTP](http://www.xlightftpd.com/index.htm) is a windows based server that authenticates using Active Directory.

On the client side you could use something like [AnyClient](http://www.anyclient.com/) which is  a java based FTP applet, that runs on any OS.

Both the client and server support SFTP as well.

Answer (score 1):

SSH server on a nix system (Unix or Linux) that supports SFTP (most/all nix do) or a compatible windows server, and have the system setup with kerb or winbind to work with the AD.  for clients, there is WinSCP for windows, and I think Mac has a built in one (not sure).

it should be noted that SFTP and FTP are not at all the same thing, SFTP is really SCP with a fancy interface, and SCP is part of SSH, while FTP is its own beast entirely.

Comment: That's true but the OP specified FTPS, which is not the same as SFTP.

Answer (score 0):

Since they already have AD credentials, this sounds like a job for a VPN.

Comment: We can't give out VPN's as that would require more rules in our already taxed firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using an FTP Java Applet?

A Java Applet can be embedded into any web page and can be configured to connect to a per-defined FTP server, the user credentials can be either prompted or passed via encrypted JavaScript variables.

Take a look at UnlimitedFTP Secure Applet, it can connect to FTP/SFTPS/FTPS servers, runs in a web page and can be integrated via JavaScript to any other web page.

http://www.utechsoft.com/products/unlimitedftp/

**Full Disclosure: This user is an employee of utechsoft.**